# How to calculate current streak in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

For a simple journal app I have the following models:

```py
class Journal(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Entry(models.Model):
    journal = models.ForeignKey(Journal)
    note = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

I want to calculate the current streak: starting from today, how many days in a row a user submitted an entry.

I have the following function (very inefficient) to calculate the current streak:

```py
def current_streak(journal):
    count = 0
    today = datetime.date.today()
    date = today-datetime.timedelta(days=count) 
    while Entry.objects.filter(journal=journal, date=date).exists():
        count += 1
        date = today-datetime.timedelta(days=count) 
    return count
```

What would be a better way to calculate this with fewer db queries?

Comment: The most performant way would be to actually have current streak for every user in DB and mantain it each time user submits a post. The logic would be quite simple: on post if entry posted yesterday increase streak count by one else reset to one. On get streak length, check if an entry were posted yesterday, if so - trust current count, else return 1 if entry was posted today, else 0. It complicates application logic, so consider this as a fallback workaround if no better solution would be suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I do have the current_streak count at the Journal model (not shown above). Does your suggestion work if user posts an entry for any day in the past, not only for yesterday?

Comment: If you allow entries to be posted at arbitrary time in past it won't work. Consider the following scenario: user post an entry at day 1, skips day 2, posts at day 3. Current streak would be one. Than, if user posts an entry for day 2, entry for day 1 exists, so suggested algorithm would increase streak length by one, resulting in two. Hovewer, actual streak length is three. So, if you allow posting at rbitrary date in past, it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do something like this is to get all your dates in one SQL query (and make sure the Django ORM actually pulls in the data with one SQL Query) and then process that information server side:

(Note that this example assumes that a one-entry journal whose date == today will be a streak of 1.)

```
def current_streak(journal):
    total_streak = 0
    current_streak = 0
    today = datetime.date.today()
    compareDate = today + datetime.timedelta(1) # Tomorrow

    # Using list() here pulls all the entries from the DB at once
    # Gets all entry dates for this journal and whose dates are <= today
    entry_dates = list(Entry.objects.values("date").filter(journal=journal, date__lte = today).order_by("-date"))

    for date in entry_dates:
        # Get the difference btw the dates
        delta = compareDate - date

        if delta.days == 1: # Keep the streak going!
            current_streak += 1
        elsif delta.days == 0: # Don't bother increasing the day if there's multiple ones on the same day
            pass
        else: # Awwww...
            break # The current streak is done, exit the loop

        compareDate = date

    if current_streak > total_streak:
        total_streak = current_streak

    return total_streak
```

Here's some information about the Django ORM and when it actually pulls in data from the DB: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

Comment: You must have meant `date__lte`, as the point is to count back. Also, since relational DBs does not guarantee ordering if not explicitly asked for, you might want to add `order_by`.

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes sense. I'll have to re-work the algo as well, as this is assuming stuff in the future. Don't know why I assumed that :)

Comment: One more point, substracting dates does not give you integer, it's `timedelta` and you can't just compare `timedelta` to 1

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'll try this. What would be a good time to calculate and store the current streak? I was thinking of adding a date field to the Journal, strike_start_date, and check if the entry being submitted is earlier than strike_start_date-1 date. If so, don't recalculate the current streak.

Comment: You could just keep the streak as an int in your Journal table, indicating the longest streak in number of days. Then every time you add an Entry to a Journal you could check to how long of a streak the new Entry is (quitting iterating when you see that delta.days > 1), then compare the streak to the one stored in the Journal table

Comment: Will do that, thanks. I just tested your code. It gives me the longest streak, not the current one.

Comment: That works great, thanks again. I ended up using the longest streak as well :)